# what means service VIP?

Tags: haproxy

[image]

Hi,
I try to understand the image above but I can't understand what VIP service is.

Is this the virtual IP address of the battery?

[image]

And there on the image above, I see IP LB. I imagine this is the real address of the LB.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual IP (VIP) is a different name for a service IP address. ("Virtual" because it is for the service overall, independent of any one backend instance.) Insert it into DNS, and give that name to the users of your load balancer or cluster.

One of those diagrams is packet based, IP headers still contain the client address. The other is a proxy, that terminates the clients session, and starts its own to the backend.

That high level diagram says nothing about *which* LB IP is the source when talking to the backend server. Could be any interface on the LB, possibly not the service address.